# Canon a2300 resolution problem

Tags: canon, image-quality, resolution

I have Canon Powershot a2300.

It was working fine till yesterday but i dnt know what settings have been changed to reduce the size of the image. Previously images sizes were about 4mb now it is kb's only , quality also reduced.
Can any one tell me how to change the resolution of the images to get the better clarity

Comment: Check your Image resolution in Settings, set it to largest available. Check your [manual](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/42039.pdf) Function Settings -> L should give you necessary settings according to that Manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [User Manual](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/cameras/digital_cameras/powershot_a2300#BrochuresAndManuals), page 62:

1. Press the FUNC. SET button, then the up/down arrows to choose L.
2. Use the left/right arrows to choose your image resolution. L should be the highest resolution (16MP)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [manual](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/42039.pdf),

- Click Function Set
- Choose "L"
- Use arrow keys to select the size you want, which would be L (large).  there are also two medium and a small setting.